# What will happen if I push changes from one branch to another?

Tags: django, git, github

I have two branches in my project.

`main` and `test_deploy`

It's incorrect to push changes without any tests to the main branch, but never mind.

I use the `main` branch to make some changes locally and the `test_deploy` where I have other changes in **settings.py** (for example DEBUG=False, use a cloud for storing my model images and so on) and files for deployment(Procfile, runtime.txt and so on).

For example, I'm going to add a new app and push it to the `main` branch and to the `test_deploy` branch too(to get the newest version of my project)

I have a question. What will happen if I commit these changes to the `main` branch, push it to this branch AND also push it to the `test_deploy` branch? Will I have conflicts that I'll have to fix manually? Or I have firstly pull all files from the `test_deploy` branch and then push it?(I don't wanna pull files from the `test_deploy` branch. That's why I asked this question)

**Summary**

So, generally, I wanna push changes from the `main` branch to `test_deploy`, but without pulling separate files from the `test_deploy` branch, because they are superfluous on the main branch which I use locally.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you correctly, but maybe `git cherry-pick` is your solution? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

You *probably* can't do this the way you want.  You might want to use cherry-pick, as [Alexandr commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487208/what-will-happen-if-i-push-changes-from-one-branch-to-another#comment124603490_70487208).

## Long

If you think of Git as being about changes, files, and/or branches, this will [lead you down the garden path](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead%20%28someone%29%20down%2Fup%20the%20garden%20path).  Don't do that: think about Git as being about *commits*, because it is.  Each commit:

- Is numbered.  A commit has a unique *hash ID*.  This is a (very large, random-*looking* but not random at all) number expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  Once Git has assigned that number to *your* new commit, it is now off limits for *every other commit ever*.<sup>1</sup>  If any other Git repository claims to have that hash ID, they must have *your* commit, not some other commit.
- Is read-only: no part of any commit (any internal Git object, really) can ever be changd.
- Stores two things: a full snapshot of every file (but compressed and Git-ified and, crucially, *de-duplicated* so that even if a million commits use a large file there's only one copy of that large file), and metadata.  The metadata generally include the raw hash IDs of other commits (usually exactly one, the previous or *parent* commit).
- Is found *by* its hash ID, which means you must provide Git with the raw hash ID, or with something Git can use to find the raw hash ID.

A *branch name* provides a raw hash ID to Git, so a branch name allows Git to find one particular commit.  That commit then provides the *previous* commit's hash ID, so that Git can find *two* commits.  The previous commit provides *its* previous commit's hash ID: this means Git can find *three* commits.  That third commit provides another hash ID, and on and on we go.

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't—[cannot be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)—true forever, but if any other Git repository uses the same number for a *different* commit, you can never have your Git fetch from or push to that other Git successfully.  The large size of hash IDs makes it plausibly true for <s>*millions*</s> er <s>*thousands*</s> urk *tens* of years (SHA-1 is no longer big enough and Git is moving to SHA-256).

---

#### Using branches

> I use the `main` branch to make some changes locally ...

What this really means is that you use the name `main` to locate some particular commit—the *latest* commit "on" your `main`.  You have Git extract the files from that commit's snapshot, so that you can read them—remember that only Git can read the Git-ified copies inside the snapshot—and write them (make your changes).

If and when you make a *new* commit, Git will:

- save the updated files;<sup>2</sup>
- save some metadata saying that you made this new commit;
- include the *current* (latest-on-`main`) commit hash ID as the *parent* of the new commit;
- write all of this out once, to a frozen snapshot copy that can never be changed at all; and
- thereby allocate a new unique hash ID, which Git now writes into your name `main`.

It's the act of making the new commit that's the most important part.  It's the fact that Git saves the new commit's hash ID under your name `main` that "changes your branch": *your* latest commit is now your new one, whose parent is whatever *was* your latest commit a moment ago.  So this is how a branch "grows," one commit at a time.

The last thing to realize here is that Git is *distributed:* you have, in your repository, *all the commits* you got from some other Git repository, which you find by your branch names, or sometimes by your *remote-tracking names* such as `origin/main`.  They have, in their Git repository, *all the commits they have*, which they find by their *branch* names.  **Their branch names are theirs; your branch names are yours.**  Keeping them in sync (whether to do it at all, and if so, how often) is up to you: your Git copies their *branch* names to your *remote-tracking names* and will update those automatically, but your Git doesn't update their *branch* names.

As you make new commits and update *your* branch names, nothing happens in the other Git repository—yet.  That's where `git push` may come in:

> So, generally, I wanna push changes from the `main` branch to `test_deploy`

Note here an important issue: there is not one (*the*) `main` branch.  There is *your* name `main` (in your Git repository), *their* name `main` (in their Git repository), and *your* name `origin/main` (in your Git repository, remembering—whenever you connect your Git to their Git and make yours update your Git's memory—what they have in theirs).

What's *shared* between your two Git repositories is not the *names*, but rather the *commits*.  When you first cloned their repository, you got *all the commits* and *none of the branches:* your Git turned all their *branch* names into *remote-tracking names*.  Then, at the end, your Git made one new branch name of your own, using the commit hash ID your Git stored under your remote-tracking name: a rather long way around to make a branch-name of the *same name* holding the *same hash ID*, but that's exactly what it did.  It's not *one branch*, it's two: both are named `main` but these in two different Git repositories.  Adding commits to your `main` does not add any commits to their `main`, nor to their `test_branch`.

---

<sup>2</sup>You must first use `git add` on each updated file, for reasons not covered in this answer.  You *can* use `git commit -a` to defer learning these reasons, but this will leave you in the dark about a number of other important Git things, so don't delay it too long.

---

#### Drawing branches

Before we talk about how `git push` works, let's *draw* some branches.  Instead of giant hexadecimal numbers, let's use uppercase letters to stand in for commit hash IDs: they're much more human-friendly.  (Of course we'll run out fast—that's why Git uses big numbers—but we'll keep our drawn branches tiny.)  We'll start off with a `main` and a `test_branch`, which we'll draw like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- test_branch
```

This is how things might look in *their* repository before you clone it.  Note that the latest commit on `main` is `H`, and the latest on `test_branch` is later—it's `I`—but the parent of `I` is `H`.  This means all the commits on `main` are also on `test_branch`.  There's just one *newer* commit on `test_branch` than there is on `main`.

When you `git clone` this repository, you get only a `main`, not a `test_branch`: your Git changes their `main` to your `origin/main`, changes their `test_branch` to your `origin/test_branch`, and then creates your own `main` from their `main`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I   <-- origin/test_branch
```

Note how *two names* identify commit `H`.  That's fine!  You can have as many names as you like that all point to one commit.  You can, if you like, *create* a *new* branch `test_branch` now pointing to commit `I`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I   <-- test_branch, origin/test_branch
```

The act of *checking out* or *switching to* `main` tells your Git repository to extract the snapshot from commit `H`—the one to which the name `main` points—and to make the name `main` the *current branch*, which we can draw by adding the word `HEAD` next to `main`.  The `git log` command does this with colored text (`HEAD -> main`, especially in `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` output); I like to do this with `main` in parentheses:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          I   <-- test_branch, origin/test_branch
```

You now change some files in your *working tree*—which is where Git put the usable copies—and maybe run some tests or whatever, and then `git add` and `git commit` as usual.  This makes a *new commit* which makes your name `main` point to the new commit.  The new commit points back to existing commit `H`, like this:

```
          J   <-- main (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I   <-- test_branch, origin/test_branch
```

Note how *nothing else happened:* the other names are undisturbed, and no existing commit has changed: `H` still points backwards to `G`, `I` still points backwards to `H`, and new `J` points backwards to `H` too.

Now we can talk about how `git push` works.  Remember that `git push` calls up *another set of Git software that works on another Git repository*.  We'll use the short name `origin`, which stores the URL at which your Git software reaches that other Git software.  You might run:

```
git push origin ...
```

where we'll fill in the `...` part in a moment.  Your Git will call up their Git and the two will converse about commits by hash IDs.  Your Git will tell them about new commit `J`, which they won't have, and then tell them about commit `J`'s parent `H`, which they *do* have.  So they'll say *please send `J` but I don't need `H` as I have that and every earlier commit too*.  Your Git can now figure out a minimal package that will deliver to them everything they need to re-create commit `J` in full, with commit `J`'s same hash ID in *their* repository.

They therefore end up with this:

```
          J   [no way to find it yet]
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- test_branch
```

Remember, *they* don't have any `origin/` names, just *their* branch names.

The last step of your `git push` is going to be your Git asking their Git to *set* one of *their* branch names.  You can choose an existing name—`main` or `test_branch` for instance—or a totally-new-to-them name.  You'll have your Git send them a polite request: *Please, if it's OK, create or update your name ________ to point to commit `J`.  Let me know if that was OK.*

Your Git will fill in the hash ID of commit `J` here based on what you give to `git push`.  Your Git will fill in the blank for the name based on what you give to your same `git push` command.  This determines what goes in the `...` part:

```
git push origin main:new_branch
```

will send them commit `J` because the part on the left of `main:new_branch` says `main`, which means *commit `J`* in *your* repository, where `main` points to `J`.  It will fill in the blank with the name `new_branch` because that's on the right of the colon in `main:new_branch`.

If you just run:

```
git push origin main
```

your Git will use the single name here—`main`—to *find the commit* in your repository (commit `J`), and also to *fill in the blank* for the name in their repository (`main`).  So that would ask them to add commit `J` to their `main`.

You want them to set their `test_branch` to point to commit `J`, though, so you might use:

```
git push origin main:test_branch
```

This asks them to set their name `test_branch` to point to commit `J`.

But what if they did do that?  They'd now have:

```
          J   <-- test_branch
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   [lost!]
```

They no longer have a way to *find* commit `I`.  They can't use their `main`: that points to commit `H`.  They can't use their name `test_branch`, if they update it, because it will point to `J`, which links back to `H`, which links back to `G`, and so on.  Nobody links *forward* (ever, in Git) and so there's no way to find commit `I`.

In short, then, they'll say *no* to your polite request.  You'll get a `! rejected` and `non-fast-forward` error from your `git push`, which is Git's jargon-esque way of saying "if I do that, I'll lose some commits".

#### So what can you do?

The problem here isn't really *branch names* per se, but rather the fact that your new commit `J` links back to existing commit `H`, and *that's* what's wrong.  You need a new commit that links back to existing commit `I`—the latest on *their* `test_branch`.

Note that before you begin doing any of this, it's advisable for you to run:

```
git fetch origin
```

This step has your Git call up their Git.  They list out all their branch names and commit hash IDs—the same thing they did back when you first ran `git clone`—and your Git can now figure out whether they have any commits that you don't have.  For instance, perhaps someone added a new commit `K` onto `test_branch`, so that they now have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--K   <-- test_branch
```

If so, your Git will obtain new commit `K` from them—your Git can tell it's new to you, because you have no commit with that number—and will then update your `origin/test_branch`—your memory of their `test_branch`—to match.

*Now* (after updating) is the time to create your own `test_branch`, pointing to the same commit they have as the last one on *their* `test_branch`.  If they're still on commit `I`, fine.  If they've added commit `K`, or even dozens of commits, that's fine too.  You'll end up with your own `test_branch` pointing to the *same commit* as their `test_branch`, which is the commit your `origin/test_branch` identifies after the `git fetch`.

In any case, whatever they have now, you can now *copy* your existing commit `J` to a new and slightly different commit—let's call this one `J'` to show how similar it is to `J`—that adds on to wherever their `test_branch` ends.  You'll run `git switch test_branch` now to create it, or `git switch test_branch && git merge --ff-only origin/test_branch` to update it, or perhaps even `git switch test_branch && git reset --hard origin/test_branch` to update your `test_branch`:

```
          J   <-- main
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I--K   <-- test_branch (HEAD), origin/test_branch
```

Now you run:

```
git cherry-pick main
```

which directs your Git to find commit `J`—as found by your name `main`—and do its best to *copy* that commit.  Copying a commit involves figuring out what the commit changed, i.e., running `git diff`, and then applying that change wherever you are now (on commit `K` in the drawing above) and making a new commit from the result.  Technically, cherry-pick is a full three-way merge, but you can, if you like, think about it as a "diff and patch" process and you won't be *too* far off.

Assuming all goes well, the end result looks like this:

```
          J   <-- main
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I--K   <-- origin/test_branch
              \
               J'   <-- test_branch (HEAD)
```

A `git show main`, which shows the difference between the snapshots in `H` and `J`, and a `git show test_branch`, which shows the difference between the snapshots in `K` and `J'`, will show the *same set of changes* (as adjusted if necessary) to the *same files changed* in `H`-vs-`J`.

You're now ready to run:

```
git push origin test_branch
```

which uses your name `test_branch` to locate commit `J'`, send that commit to `origin`—they already have everything that comes *before* `J'` so you just send the one commit—and then ask them to add commit `J'` to *their* `test_branch`.  Since that adds on to `K`, they'll probably accept this polite request.

Comment: "You can, if you like, create a new branch test_branch now pointing to commit I" The way I think I would do this is `git checkout -b test_branch origin/test_branch` Is this also what you had in mind? 

Furthermore, is there somehow I can track or **synch** `test_branch` to `origin/test_branch` instead of just creating an arbitrary new branch name to point to the same commit as `origin/test_branch` ? What I mean by **synch**ing here is that `test_branch` locally will forever track `origin/test_branch`.

Comment: "your Git changes their main to your origin/main, changes their test_branch to your origin/test_branch, and then creates your own main from their main:" What is so special about `main` both at our end and their end that this specific branch alone gets the special treatment of not only getting `origin/main` (which test_branch also got) but in addition to that `main` locally also points to this? Is this guaranteed in the sense  that this special treatment is accorded only to `main` or can it apply to `master` as well?

Comment: You answered my first question later on in the answer here: "You'll run git switch test_branch now to create it, or git switch test_branch && git merge --ff-only origin/test_branch to update it, or perhaps even git switch test_branch && git reset --hard origin/test_branch to update your test_branch" Thanks!

Comment: You state: "You'll run git switch test_branch now to create it," This is a bit unclear. A local `test_branch` does not exist prior to this command. Locally, we do have `origin/test_branch`. In this case, how would `git switch test_branch` *know* that this local `test_branch` should map to `origin/test_branch` ? Is it some sort of a guess based on matching branch names you had alluded to earlier in response to a question of mine on a different thread?

Comment: Indeed. You have answer the question quite detailedly over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587730/cloning-a-remote-repository-and-subsequent-offline-access-to-it#comment126525961_71587730

Comment: a very minor suggestion -- please indicate where HEAD would be after the cherry-pick in your very last figure. I suppose it would continue to be at the new updated test_branch that now points at J'

Comment: @Tryer: fixed the missing HEAD. As for main/master/whatever, it isn't really special here: instead, when you run `git clone`, you provide a `-b <branch>` to say which branch name your `git clone` command should create. But if you *don't* provide `-b`, your software asks their software which branch name they "recommend" (which amounts to figuring out which branch *their* `HEAD` names). If they say `main`, you get `-b main`. If they say `dev`, you get `-b dev`.