# Cloning a remote repository and subsequent offline access to it

Tags: git

Consider the following commands issued on a local computer:

```
git clone git://git.test.git # <- creates folder test in current folder
cd test # amongst other files/folders, this contains the .git subfolder
git branch -r # <- to show the remote branches
```

Suppose the output of this is:

```
origin/C
origin/B -> origin/master
origin/A
```

(1) Is the size of `test\.git` folder, the actual and complete size of the online remote repository including all branches and all commits in each of these branches? I understand that the objects in `.git` folder are possibly compressed and uncompressing them is likely to increase size of the `test` folder. That is okay since I would like to know the full compressed and yet *complete* size of the remote repository. I am *not* interested to know the full *uncompressed* size of the remote repository.

(2) Is it safe to turn off the internet connection now on the local machine and issue:

```
git checkout C
```

to checkout branch `C` or does each checkout after a clone need to access the remote repository again over the internet?

---

ETA: Following up on [torek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) comment:

> When you run `git checkout C`, your Git is about to give you an error
> ("I could not find a branch named C")

I do not get this error. I obtained:

```
Branch 'C' set up to track remote branch 'C' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'C'
```

---

Indeed, as torek implied, running `git checkout C --no-guess` gave error:

`error: pathspec 'C' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: yes you have everything in local, you get all the history all the branches ,etc. Just try it you will see

Comment: @Ôrel Would therefore the size of the online repo just be the size of the `.git` folder?

Comment: its kinda complicated to answer whether the size of remote repo is the same with our local `.git` folder. if you clone a repository that utilizes git `lfs` for storing certain files, your `.git` folder only contains pointer (usually an url and hash) to those files instead of the actual files. with `git lfs` after a checkout, you are required to pull them manually using `git lfs fetch origin master` to get them (some prefers: `git lfs fetch --all` so they can have the entire historical state of the files). you can find the [docs here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/).

Comment: The name *remote branch* is misleading: what you have in `origin/C` is a *local* name, which I call a *remote-tracking name* (Git's formal version of this is "remote-tracking branch name"). The names simply identify specific commits. When you ran `git clone`, Git made a new empty repository, then copied *all* the commits from the source Git repository into your new empty repository, then took all their *branch* names and *renamed* them to be remote-tracking names (`origin/C` instead of `C` for instance).

Comment: When you run `git checkout C`, your Git is about to give you an error ("I could not find a branch named C") when it notices: hey, there's no `C` but there is `origin/C`, I *guess* you meant `git checkout --track C origin/C`. So it does that. You can turn that off with `--no-guess` but once you know that's what it does, that's usually want you *want* done. After it does that, you have a branch name `C` (a "local" branch, but all names are local anyway) that you can do whatever you want with.

Comment: The new branch name initially points to the *same commit* as their `C`, your `origin/C`, so if you look at the commit you just checked out, you'll see the same files as if you look at a checkout of commit `C` in their Git repository, at this point. Moreover, your (local) `C` has its *upstream* set to `origin/C`, so that your Git knows to compare the commits against their `C` = your `origin/C`. You can disconnect now, reconnect later, run `git fetch`, and at `git fetch` time your Git will reach out to their Git, find any new commits they have, get all of those, and update your `origin/*` names.

Comment: You don't get an error. Just *before* you *would* get an error, Git activates the `--guess` option. (If you use `--no-guess`, *then* you'll get the error.)

Comment: @Tryer Why do you want to know if your local repo is the same size as the remote? Is this a proxy for some other concern?

Comment: @Schwern My concern is that I have done so many commits (containing excel files, zip files, data files) in one of my repos (around 40 or so) and still the `.git` folder on my machine is just *only* around 4 MB or so. I find that difficult to believe. If I took all of the files that I have ever committed and made one zip file of it I would be surprised if the zip file is just 4 MB or so, but I suppose that is exactly what it would turn out to be.

Comment: @Tryer Git is really efficient. Or you're using git-lfs. If you decompress and unzip files before committing them Git can store them even more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) Is the size of test.git folder, the actual and complete size of the online remote repository including all branches and all commits in each of these branches?

There might be some difference in the size, but yes, `git clone` gives you a complete copy of the repository and it will be roughly the same size as on the remote.

> (2) Is it safe to turn off the internet connection now on the local machine and issue `git checkout C` to checkout branch C or does each checkout after a clone need to access the remote repository again over the internet?

Git is *always* in offline mode. With the exception of a handful of commands (`fetch`, `push`, `pull` being the most common) Git is *always* working from your local .git directory. You must explicitly tell Git to access the remote repositories.

Note that remotes don't have to be over the internet. You can, for example, clone a directory and experiment. `git clone /path/to/some/other/repository`.