# Cannot see cloned repositry in my local Drive

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have cloned a repository in my local machine from GitHub using git but it showed me only readme note.

In actuality it has two branches master and main the project is in master not in main and readme file is in main and when I do clone it shows me only readme file...

Tell me any solution or anything which is I am missing in it..

**I have just noticed that it has cloned only one branch "master" not all**...
**Why???**

Comment: If you see anything at all (e.g. the clone directory, containing the readme note) you _are_ seeing the repository, so do not say you can't see it.

Comment: `git clone` plain and simple clones the entire repository. You can confirm that by saying `git branch -avv`. You should see not only `master` but also `remotes/origin/master` and `remotes/origin/main` (if there really is a main). That's the clone — the stuff in `remotes/origin/...`. I'm sure you'll find it's all there.

Comment: Cloning copies the entire repo to your machine and then checks out the default branch. If you want to see your local file system change to look like a different branch then checkout a different branch.

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` *always* copies all (or most; see below) of the *commits* and *none* of the *branches*.  That's the correct thing for it to do.

A Git repository is, at its heart, two databases:

- One database holds all the commits and other internal (supporting) Git objects.  This database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), with the keys being hash IDs and the values being the objects (commits and others).  This database is generally much larger (some oddball projects wind up with this database being smaller, but we'll call this the "big" one).
- The other database holds *names:* branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, `refs/stash` if you have some stashes, and so on.

The `git clone` process literally copies the big database, because the *commits* are the important part.  The *names* help you (and Git) *find* the commits, but your branch names are not anyone else's branch names, nor vice versa, so `git clone` *does not* copy these.  Instead, your Git software reads their *branch* names and turns those into your *remote-tracking names*.

Once the clone has finished copying these databases, and set up the rest of what you need to get new work done—this "get work done" part is optional but you wouldn't normally omit it—your Git software then goes on to create *one* branch.  You can create as many more branches as you like after this point.

The one branch your software creates is the one you choose when you run `git clone`, like this:

```
git clone -b develop ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
```

The `-b` flag tells your Git which branch name *you* want to create.

If you *leave out* the `-b` flag, your Git will ask their Git which branch name *they recommend*.  They'll usually recommend `main` or `master`, but anyone who controls a GitHub repository can use the GitHub web pages to set which branch they recommend for their repository.  Git calls this the *default branch*.  (For some reason Google's repository setup won't let you change this and it's stuck on `master`, *even if there is no branch named `master`*.)

You *can* use `--single-branch` or `--depth` to make what Git calls a *single-branch* clone.  Here, your Git will obtain somewhat less than *all* the commits from the other Git repository, and will copy only *one* of their branch names to your corresponding remote-tracking name.  For instance:

```
git clone -b branch42 --single-branch ssh://git@github.com/adams/hhgttg.git
```

(if there were such a repository) might clone just the branch where the mice intend to store the question, once it's figured out (we know the *answer* to the ultimate question about Life, the Universe, and Everything is 42, but we don't know the *question*).  This works by cloning the commits that are reachable *from* that branch name, then creating `origin/branch42` in your new clone, then creating as the one branch name in *your* repository, a new branch named `branch42` that refers to the same commit as your `origin/branch42`, i.e., *their* latest commit as of this moment.

(Single-branch and/or shallow clones are a bit of an oddball case and can give you heartburn later, so be sure you want one before you make one.  They can be undone later though: search StackOverflow, where the answers already exist, if you can just figure out the question.)

Having cloned *all* the commits and copied *all* their branches to remote-tracking names, you can just run:

```
git switch --guess branch42
```

or whatever.  The `--guess` option means *look at all my `origin/*` names and guess which one of those corresponds to the branch I don't have yet so that you can create that branch for me automatically*.  And in fact, `--guess` is the *default*, so you don't need to specify it: it exists so that you can run:

```
git switch --no-guess branch42
```

and prevent guessing, in case you don't want the branch created if there isn't already a `branch42`, regardless of whether or not there's an `origin/branch42` name.

Comment: `git clone -b develop ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` The -b flag tells your Git which branch name you want to create. Case (1) Their side does not have a branch named develop. Then, do we get our local `develop` track their recommended `main` or `master`? Or does git show an error? Case (2) Their side does have a branch named develop. In this case, I suppose as you have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587730/cloning-a-remote-repository-and-subsequent-offline-access-to-it#comment126525961_71587730) my develop will track their develop via origin/develop. Am I right?

Comment: @Tryer: test it out on some repository you can clone (use `git ls-remote` first to see which branch names they have). I did leave one thing out on purpose (for space reasons): you can also supply a *tag* name to `-b`, which makes your Git copy their commits and then go into detached-HEAD mode, as if you ran `git checkout <tag>`. You wind up with no local branches, as if you ran `git clone --no-checkout` followed by `git switch --detach <tag>`.

Comment: If I provide: `git clone -b xyz git://abc/def.git`, where `xyz` is not found one of "their" branches, I obtain: `fatal: Remote branch xyz not found in upstream origin`. If I say `git clone -b devel git://abc/def.git`, where `devel` is one of "their" branches, I seem to be automatically checked out in that branch. This is equivalent to `git clone git://abc/def.git` followed by `git checkout devel`.

Comment: More specifically: In the latter two working cases, I obtain the same as the result of `git status`: `On branch devel Your branch is up to date with 'origin/devel'. nothing to commit, working tree clean`
Given this, I will read through your answers once again to firm these ideas in my mind. Thanks!

Comment: When after cloning via `git clone git://abc/def.git`, I give `git branch -r`, the output is all in red font with `origin/A, origin/B,...`, and so on. One of these lines alone is "special" with `origin/HEAD -> origin/master`. The `origin/HEAD` is in red, while `origin/master` is in white font. My interpretation is that it is the HEAD branch on remote that has gotten automatically checked out as my local master which is tracking origin/master. Is this right? That is, "their" repository's current head is pointing at "their" master which is now my master and origin/master.

Comment: @Tryer: yes: first your Git calls up their Git to see what they have (and whether anyone answers).  Use `git ls-remote <url>` to see what spills out at this point. There's an old protocol where their `HEAD` comes out as a raw hash ID, and a new one (enabled only if your Git asks for it but this happened back in the 1.7-ish era) where their `HEAD` comes out as a symbolic ref. With the new protocol, your Git knows what name is in their `HEAD`, assuming they have an attached HEAD, otherwise you still get a raw hash ID. Then, in any case, [continued]

Comment: ... then your own Git will use their HEAD branch name as the default `-b`, and if you specified `-b`, require that the name you gave match a branch or tag name that spilled out at this point. If they don't support the new protocol (or your Git doesn't ask for it) and you get a raw hash ID for their HEAD, your Git tries to match up the hash ID gotten to one of their branch names, and then *guesses* that their `HEAD` is attached to that branch name, and proceeds from there.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be we need to change the directory for an example if we clone dev_api in git bash then we need to switch the branch in git bash like cd dev_api ,it will show we are master branch and Then we need to checkout branch into feature branch like " git checkout feature/mydev" which we import into any IDE for changes