# local repository not showing and files and folders

Tags: windows, git, github

I just cloned my repo from my GitHub account but I'm unable to see any files and folders on my local machine except the .git folder. When I run the `git pull` command, it says `Already up to date` and when I run `git push` command then it again says `Everything is up-to-date`.

I can assure you that my remote repo is not empty. It has many files and folders.

[image]

Below is my remote repo screenshot
[image]

Comment: Check if this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71712407/12152180

Comment: @RafaelMoreira no that is not helpful at all :(

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v` and `git status`?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have 2 branches, maybe your default branch if not main in this repo.

Try

```
git checkout "otherbranch"
```

or

```
git switch "otherbranch"
```

Comment: I have 2 branches remote, not local. Anyways both 2 branches have the same content. None of those are empty.

Comment: Could you post the whole clone command you're using and the msg that shows after cloning? Thanks.