# Working on new feature , git clone or pull?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

Lets say I clone a repository from remote, on my local I created new branch made changed and pushed this branch to remote where master and new branch is merged.

The next time when I need to work on new feature do I need to clone or pull the remote repository ? or git fetch

Whenever I start work on new feature do I have to get the latest copy of master branch ?

Comment: Both clone and pull are, to some extent, convenience wrappers around more fundamental operations. (`clone` does an init, sets up a remote, then pulls from the remote; `pull` does a fetch and a merge.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git clone is required for only the first time to get copy of the repository to local.

You can create new feature branch from master to work on it. Once done, you can push and merge changes to master (Even delete the feature once you are done)

To avoid conflicts while creating new branches, it is best practice to git pull from master, create a feature branch and then make changes to your local repository.
In case you have any local changes already, you can choose to git stash them and switch to new branch (and unstash your changes in new branch)

Answer (score 3):

You only need to clone the remote repository once. After that, a git pull will always retrieve the latest changes from the remote repository for the branch you're currently on.

So if you want to develop the next feature, you could simply checkout your master branch, git pull it and you're up to date. Then you can create a new branch and start working.

Comment: git pull always create conflict and ask me to fix, that is why I was thinking of git clone

Comment: Have you made any local changes since you last pushed to the remote repository?

Comment: @alex3465 But that's a completely different problem. You didn't mention the conflict in your question. This is a reasonable answer to the question _that you actually asked_.

Comment: No I do not do any changes in my local , changes are done in remote so when I pull the remote repo since both are different now so it raise the merge conflict , I thought that is normal scenario

Answer (score 2):

You will only ever work on feature branches locally. (Merging happens on the server.) So what you want is a simple fetch.

Here's how to work.

- Never make a local `master` branch. If you have one now, left over from the clone, delete it.
- To update your repo from the remote, say `git fetch --prune`.
- To start a new feature branch, say `git switch -c myFeature origin/master`.

That's all. Never say `pull`. No need to clone again. No conflicts in your repo.

Comment: "Never make a local master branch. If you have one now, left over from the clone, delete it." Suppose a remote has its own `master` branch where HEAD currently point to there, when I clone it on my machine, does that not get a name `origin/master` at my end and also a local name `master` that is automatically checked out? This is my understanding from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487208/what-will-happen-if-i-push-changes-from-one-branch-to-another/70492141?noredirect=1#comment126634323_70492141

Comment: Yep, and I'm saying delete the local `master`.

Comment: You and torek are my git gurus. Thank you!

Comment: Everything I know I learned from torek!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps which you can follow

1. Git Clone (When you first start)
2. Create a branch from Master
3. Git Pull (this is important)
4. Merge with master (or use Pull request)

Step 3 is important, You need to Pull before merge and before you actually create your branch from master.

Comment: should I merge feature branch on local and then pull request   or push feature branch to remote then  pull  request ?

Comment: It really depends, in many companies developer can not merge to main without code review, they use pull request. If you are the only person working you can merge directly into main.  But technically you should pull before push. (in fact I prefer to pull code frin remote many times a day, it does not harm)